# Efficient equality function on trees

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, time-complexity, sml

A few days ago, I was given the following interview question. It was described with Standard ML code, but I was free to answer with the language of my choice (I picked Python):

> I have a type:
>
> ```
> datatype t 
>   = Leaf of int
>   | Node of (t * t)
> ```
>
> and a function, `f` with the signature
>
> ```
> val f: int -> t
> ```
>
> You need to write a function `equals` that checks whether two trees
>   are equal. `f` is `O(n)`, and it does "the worst possible
>   thing" for the time complexity of your `equals` function. Write
>   `equals` such that it is *never* exponential on `n`, the argument to
>   `f`.

The example of `f` that was provided was:

```
fun f n = 
  if n = 0 then 
    Leaf(0)
  else 
    let 
      val subtree = f (n - 1) 
    in
      Node (subtree, subtree)
    end
```

which produces an exponentially large tree in `O(n)` time, so `equals (f(n), f(n))` for the naive `equals` implementation that's linear on the number of nodes of the tree is `O(2^n)`.

I produced something like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Leaf:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

def equals(left, right):
    if left is right:
        return True
    try:
        return left.value == right.value 
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        return equals(left.left, right.left) and equals(left.right, right.right)
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

which worked on the example of `f` that the interviewer provided, but failed in the general case of "`f` does the worst thing possible." He provided an example that I don't remember that broke my first attempt. I flubbed around for a bit and eventually made something that looked like this:

```
cache = {}
def equals(left, right):
    try:
        return cache[(left, right)]
    except KeyError:
        pass

    result = False
    try:
        result = left.value == right.value 
    except ValueError:
        pass
    try:
        left_result = equals(left.left, right.left) 
        right_result = equals(left.right, right.right)
        cache[(left.left, right.left)] = left_result
        cache[(left.right, right.right)] = right_result
        result = left_result and right_result
    except ValueError:
        pass

    cache[(left, right)] = result
    return result
```

but I felt like that was an awkward hack and it clearly wasn't what the interviewer was looking for. I suspect that there's an elegant way to avoid recomputing subtrees -- what is it?

Comment: Memoization is the first thing that came to my mind too.

Comment: Wait, you are supposed to get sublinear time for equals? I don't think that's possible in general. Is there a restriction that `f(n)` will use at most O(n) unique nodes so that memoization actually helps you in the worst case? E.g. this would be the case if `f` returns a strict, fully evaluated tree (due to the time constraint)

Comment: @NiklasB. The restriction is that `f(n)` is `O(n)`, which I think implies that it makes at most `O(n)` unique nodes.

Comment: @PatrickCollins If the returned tree is fully evaluated, that is correct

Comment: By the way, I think your final solution is O(n^2) in the worst case, not O(n)

Comment: @NiklasB. I was turned down for the position, so I assume I did something wrong. I'm having trouble thinking about what "`O(n)` unique nodes arranged somehow in the tree" looks like and the ways that a comparison function can fail.

Comment: @Patrick Collins: “I was turned down for the position”. I guess they see that you are asking here. ;-)

Comment: @Patrick Collins: “what "O(n) unique nodes arranged somehow in the tree" looks like.” Nodes are objects in the **heap** that contain addresses of objects. Here, a node contains 2 identical addresses. It's language implementation.

Comment: The function `f` you were provided does infinite recursion.

Comment: @beroal My mistake, it should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution as such is O(n^2) by the looks of it. We can make it O(n) by using memoization on the identity of a single tree, rather than a pair of trees:

```
memoByVal = {}
memoByRef = {id(None): 0}
nextId = 1

# produce an integer that represents the tree's content
def getTreeId(tree):
  if id(tree) in memoByRef:
    return memoByRef[id(tree)]
  # nodes are represented by the (left, right, value) combination
  # let's assume that leafs just have left == right == None
  l, r = getTreeId(tree.left), getTreeId(tree.right)
  if (l, r, tree.value) not in memoByVal:
    memoByVal[l, r, tree.value] = nextId
    nextId += 1
  res = memoByVal[l, r, tree.value]
  memoByRef[id(tree)] = res
  return res

# this is now trivial
def equals(a, b):
  return getTreeId(a) == getTreeId(b)
```

Comment: This is not possible in SML.  There is no id function.  You can not just grab the memory location of an arbitrary value, which would break type abstraction.

Comment: @seanmcl I was allowed to use the language of my choice. But given that the interviewer was a Standard ML programmer, I assume that the solution he wanted was possible to implement in Standard ML.

Comment: @seanmcl  In a referentially transparent language the task is impossible to solve. OP is allowed to use any language though

Comment: @Niklas B.: You forgot to return `res`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [hash consing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing) to create replicas of both trees in linear time and then compare them for equality in constant time.

Here is an example of hash consing in sml.

https://github.com/jhckragh/SMLDoc/tree/master/smlnj-lib/HashCons

Update:

See comments.  I was too hasty in this answer.  I don't think it's possible to create the replica in linear time.  You'd need to start with the hash-consed type, and only use those constructors in f.

Comment: Ah! The interview began with some questions about hash tables that I thought were unrelated. This sounds like the ticket. I'm going to wait a bit to accept an answer but I suspect you've gotten it.

Comment: Isn't this linear in the total number of nodes, which can be exponential in n? I don't quite understand how you could implement this efficiently on the given type without lower-level (referential transparency-breaking) hacks.

Comment: SML isn't referentially transparent.  It has state, e.g. refs and hashtables.

Comment: @Niklas: You're right though that it's not clear to me how to translate a given value of type t to a hash-consed variant without traversing the nodes using just pattern matching, which would yield exponential time if you tried equal(f(N), f(N)).  I believe you'd need to change the type t.